# How to count the length of a tuple in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I tried searching in web and stackexchange, but surprisingly no one asked how to calculate length of a tuple in Haskell in the form below.

So suppose you have tuple like (1,2,3,4) or (1,3,5,6,7) in Haskell and wish to write the length function that calculates length of a tuple. How can I do this? For list I know how I will be able to do so using recursion without explicitly invoking built-in functions. But tuple is different, and I can't use "head"-"tail" distinction.

Will the method involve creating a new data type?

Comment: What would the type of such a function be?

Comment: That's the point of asking this question. I cannot perceive how this is going to be possible. Tuples of different lengths will not share the same type, and I don't know how I may exploit creating a new data type to support the length function.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this? The length of a tuple is fixed at compile time, so there should be no need to “calculate” anything. You could use a typeclass like `class TupLen a where tupLen :: a -> Int` with `instance TupLen (a, b) where tupLen _ = 2`, &c., but this isn’t very useful.

Answer (score 7):

The reason you don't find anything on this is that it doesn't make a lot of sense to count the length of a tuple:

- It is pre-determined a compile time (i.e. you might just as well hard-code it)
- There's not really much you could do with that information: unlike with e.g. a list, it's not possible to *index* specific entries in a generic tuple.

That said, it is possible to achieve your goal, however this shouldn't be a normal function but a *type-level function*, aka type family. Using [singleton](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.2) type nats:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DataKinds #-}
import Data.Singletons
import Data.Singletons.TypeLits

type family TupLength a :: Nat where
  TupLength () = 0
  TupLength (a,b) = 2
  TupLength (a,b,c) = 3
  TupLength (a,b,c,d) = 4
  -- ...
  TupLength x = 1
```

Then

```
> mapM_ print [ natVal (sing :: SNat (TupLength ()))
              , natVal (sing :: SNat (TupLength (Int,String,Double)))
              , natVal (sing :: SNat (TupLength Bool)) ]
0
3
1
```

Answer (score 5):

One possible answer (using just the base library) is

```
import Data.Data
import Data.Functor.Const

length :: Data a => a -> Int
length =
  getConst .
  gfoldl (\(Const c) _ -> Const (c+1)) (const 0)
```

I gave a whole talk on this subject at London Haskell recently. The slides are [here](https://ro-che.info/docs/2017-05-17-generic-traversals.pdf), but the video has not been published yet.

Comment: Worth noting that this will give “length info” not just for tuples but also all kinds of other data structures, perhaps not always with the intended results.